# Check the character encoding of a given page in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, encoding

Character encoding of an HTML document is determined by looking at [various things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12406142/616460) (encoding in `Content-Type` header, `meta` elements, BOMs in data, etc.)

In Chrome (56), is there a way to view the ultimate character encoding that it determined a given page was using?

I've been poking around in the developer tools but nothing is popping out at me. I did find that you can view the `Content-Type` headers in the *Network* tab but this doesn't cover the case where the encoding isn't specified there.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In the Chrome console:

```
document.characterSet
```

This is the encoding used to display the page, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/characterSet):

> The `Document.characterSet` read-only property returns the character encoding of the current document. The character encoding is the character set used for rendering the document, which may be different from the encoding specified by the page. (The user can override the encoding.).